# Adding and removing stations in 802.3 vs 802.4 vs 802.5

Tags: networking, ethernet, wifi

Good day everyone.
I've been searching for information on how the process of adding and removing stations occurs in different network standards, all I found is scarce informations about the 802.4 standard. I know its using a logical ring which i think makes medium access similar to 802.5, does adding and removing stations take place in the same manner ? And what about Ethernet ?